# Как разобрать строку на части?

Tags: php

Имеется строка по типу:

```
user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

Как для каждого значения в строке создать новую переменную?

Например:

```
$variable = "user1";
$variable = "user2";
```

В строке могу содержаться любые значения через запятую.

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

При необходимости ещё можно после ф-ции *array_combine()* выполнить **extract($users);** и тогда в текущей области видимости появятся одноимённые переменные, значения которых будут совпадать с их именами.

```
$str = 'user1, user2, user3, user4, user5';

$users = explode(', ', $str);
$users = array_combine($users, $users);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($users); echo '</pre>';
/*
array(5) {
  ["user1"]=>
  string(5) "user1"
  ["user2"]=>
  string(5) "user2"
  ["user3"]=>
  string(5) "user3"
  ["user4"]=>
  string(5) "user4"
  ["user5"]=>
  string(5) "user5"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант.

```html
$string  = "user1, user2, user3, user4, user5";
$array = explode(", ", $string);

extract( $array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "my_prefix_");
```

Оригинал примера [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#25314).